# Get all map values as a slice?

Tags: go

Say I have the following map:

```
d := map[string]int{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
}
```

How can I get the values in the map as a slice? eg. `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 3):

```
m := make([]int, 0, len(d))
for _, val := range d {
    m = append(m, val)
}
```

Note: the order of the slice is not deterministic; you may have to reorder it, depending on your use case.